# c# How to get point data from chart on click?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get a point on a chart that the user pressed.
From what I see and researched, the Click and MouseClick events only give you information about the mouse position in pixels on the window.
is there a way to get information about the point pressed?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, there is. You can use the axes functions to convert mouse positions both to relative positions and to axis values. You can also try a Hittest to see if a datapont got hit directly. (simple for largish hard for smallish points..) - If it wasn't, you may have to search the points for the one nearest to the clicked values. [See here for many related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+pixel). (Not all may be relevant, though..

Answer (score 2):

using `Chart.HitTest` you get an `HitTestResult` type object that holds information about the location pressed. Then you can do whatever you want with it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.hittestresult(v=vs.110).aspx